# Passing props in child component from state of parent component

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to use the state from Parent Component to child component on Google Maps component. This may sound a very basic question, however I am trying to understand the difference between one of props working and other not.

So I have a google maps component (import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react')

```
static defaultProps = {
    center: { lat: 62.10281, lng: -84.14565 },
    zoom: 11
  };

  constructor(props) {
   console.log(props);       
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

      return (
        <div className='google-map' style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
          <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'somekey' }}
            center={this.props.center}
            defaultZoom={ this.props.zoom }>
            <AnyReactComponent
              lat={ this.props.lat }
              lng={ this.props.lng }
              text={ 'Wheres Waldo?' }
            />
          </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
      )
  }
```

and then from parent component

```
<MapComponent lat={this.state.latitude} lng={this.state.longitude}
                    center={{lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitude}}
```

I have checked the value to lat, lng and center in constructor and I am getting them as expected still map doesn't work

However, If I hardcode the value in center leaving the lat and lng getting value from state, then it does work.

Now this works, Can someone please explain this concept and the difference and how to overcome it? Your help is appreciated.

```
<MapComponent lat={this.state.latitude} lng={this.state.longitude}
                    center={{lat: 62.10281, lng: -84.14565}}
```

Comment: Put `console.log(this.props);` into the render function before the return block. Tell us what's in the console in both of your testcases.

Comment: I am getting the values I expect


center: {lat: "62.10281", lng: "-84.14565"}
lat: "62.10281"
lng: "-84.14565"
zoom: 11

Comment: So the values are exactly the same in both cases hardcoded and from parent.state? Is there any error thrown?

Comment: No error in console. That is I find strange and assumed I don't know some core concept. Is Child component rendered before this value is mapped.
Just a note that the values coming from parent component are coming from an API, so possible that when child component is rendered, the values were not present. However, console log clearly state the values being logged.